# Image Navigation Using text-indent

Tags: css, xhtml, navigation, text-indent

I'm trying to create a simple image navigation for my site, using CSS to declare the `background-image` property of a list-item (li). The problem is, when I use `text-indent` to put the image off-screen, the link is no longer there (off screen as well I presume). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my XHTML:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="current about">
      <a href="#about" title="about">about</a>
    </li>
    <li class="contact">
      <a href="#contact" title="contact">contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="networks">
      <a href="#networks" title="networks">networks</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#nav li {
   display: block;
   float:left;
   background-image: url("images/nav-normal.png");
   height:47px;
   text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

I have also set up background-positions for the individual list-items because I'm using [image sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply that style to the `#nav li a`.  Otherwise everything inside the `li`, including the link, is shifted off screen.

Comment: Thanks so much! Knew I was doing something wrong! Worked perfectly!